# Rails iteration from session

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, iteration

I have the following stored in my session:

```
session[:quoteResponse]['6000']['something'][...]
session[:quoteResponse]['6000']['something_else'][...]

session[:quoteResponse]['8000']['something'][...]
session[:quoteResponse]['8000']['something_else'][...]

session[:quoteResponse]['10000']['something'][...]
session[:quoteResponse]['10000']['something_else'][...]
```

How can I iterate through them in a view to achieve the following?

```
<div class="product">
    <%= radio_button_tag 'form[baseMiles]', '6000' %>
    <label for="form_baseMiles_6000">6,000 Policy Miles</label>
    <a class="need-more-miles" href="#">Need more miles? <span>View</span></a>
</div>

<div class="product">
    <%= radio_button_tag 'form[baseMiles]', '8000' %>
    <label for="form_baseMiles_8000">8,000 Policy Miles</label>
    <a class="need-more-miles" href="#">Need more miles? <span>View</span></a>
</div>

<div class="product">
    <%= radio_button_tag 'form[baseMiles]', '10000' %>
    <label for="form_baseMiles_10000">10,000 Policy Miles</label>
    <a class="need-more-miles" href="#">Need more miles? <span>View</span></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see why this won't work

```
<% session[:quoteResponse].each do |miles, other_properties| %>
  <div class="product">
    <%= radio_button_tag 'form[baseMiles]', miles.to_s %>
    <label for="form_baseMiles_<%= miles %>"><%= miles %> Policy Miles</label>
    <a class="need-more-miles" href="#">Need more miles? <span>View</span></a>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Other properties will contain "something" and "something else" as a hash, in case you need them.

Comment: Given as correct as it specifically answers the question - thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Well, depending on where 'something' and 'something_else' should go you can

```
<% session[:quoteResponse].each do |num, arr| %>
  <% arr.each do |item| %>
    ...
    here you can use num to refer to 6000, 10000 and item to each 'something', 'something_else'
    ...
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

I hope, this helps.

Comment: This was helpful but not given as correct as it did not specifically answer my question - thanks though !